# Azure CLI, Create VM with domainNames

Tags: linux, networking, command-line, virtual-machine, azure

Any easy way to Create Azure VM with domainNames with Azure CLI?

Seem to me the steps are rather complicated in
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/create-cli-complete
involving creating vnet, public-ip, network nsg, network nsg rule, network nic, etc, etc.

**UPDATE:**

All I want is to give my created VM a public accessible sub domainName under Azure, so that I can access it with domainName not via IP, which is what the [quickstart](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/quickstart) gives me. It used to be that, a while back when I was creating VM via the web portal, if I give my VM a name, say `mypublicvmname`, then Azure creats a subdomain under its own. Now, with Azure CLI, what's the most easy way to achieve that please? Because having reviewed @PimpJuiceIT's suggestion https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-delegate-domain-azure-dns, I still don't see an easy (or any) way of doing that, because that article (and the related within the tutorial) keeps talking about custom domainNames and private DNS zones.

Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> All I want is to give my created VM a public accessible sub domainName
>   under Azure, so that I can access it with domainName not via IP, which
>   is what the quickstart gives me.

For your issue, as I know you want to access your Azure VM with domainName not via IP.

In Azure, the domainName associated to the IP that you can access the VM, and it's not a resource but a configuration of public IP.

So, if you just looking for a simple way to create a Azure VM with domainName with Azure CLI. You need to do two steps at least.

- **First**, create a Azure VM with the default settings, including virtual
  network, NSG and public IP and so that. You just set resource group
  name, vm name, user name, password and image. For this, you can use command like this:

  `az vm create --resource-group resourceGroupName --name vmName --image UbuntuLTS --admin-username userName --admin-password password --location eastus`

  The out put will like this:
  [image]
- **Second**, set domainName for the public IP. You can use command like this to get the public IP info:

  `az network public-ip list --resource-group resourceGroupName --output table`

  And the out put will like this:
  [image]

  And use command like this to set domainName:

  `az network public-ip update --resource-group resourceGroupName --name publicipName --dns-name domainName`

  The out put will like this:
  [image]

When all things be OK. You can access the VM with domainName. By the way, you'd better make sure that your nsg have configured correctly.